# How to pass aws iot x.509 certificate path in java

Tags: java, x509certificate, aws-iot

I'm using aws lambda function which is internally using aws iot core to publish message to connected devices. I have generated x509 certificate from aws console and kept it inside resources folder of spring boot project but calling lambda function throwing `FileNotFoundException`

**I have already tried following ways:**

1)

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File cityFile = new 
    File(classLoader.getResource("test.txt").getFile());
```

2) Added following resource tag in `pom.xml` inside build tag

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>7913fa14e2-certificate.pem.crt</include>
                    <include>7913fa14e2-private.pem.key</include>
                </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

3) My fields:

```
    private static final String certificateFile = "src/main/resources/7913fa14e2-certificate.pem.crt";
```

4) Code:

```
    File file = new File(certificateFile);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Certificate file: " + filename + " is not found.");
        return null;
    }

    try (BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new 
    FileInputStream(file))) {
        final CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        return (List<Certificate>) certFactory.generateCertificates(stream);
    } catch (IOException | CertificateException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load certificate file " + filename);
    }
    return null;
```

5) Error:

```
    File file = new File(filename);
```

this line throwing `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Have you considered using the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/iotdata/AWSIotDataAsyncClient.html) to avoid the need to store and read certificates?

Comment: @blt I'm already using AWS SDK and we have two options in aws iot core sdk to create awsIotClient object . one is by passing certifcate and private file paths and second is using awsAccessKeyId and awsSecretAccessKey. I'm able to create object by second method but I'm not really sure if it is the ideal or secure way of doing this.that's why I wanted to explore first option to get this awsIotClient object.

Comment: Ok - you might want to try using LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT in the path to reference your certificate.

Comment: Link to this environment variable: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-environment-variables.html